# "She came ____ me and asked the best way to get ____ the situation"

Tags: prepositions

Question:

> She came ____me and asked the best way to ____ the situation.
>
> a) towards / over
>   　b) up to / out of

My approach:

I am confused between *towards* and *up to* because *towards* indicate movement in the direction of and also I found *up to* which I have not found any correlation with the sentence.

Here is what I found:

> 1) as far as: I could reach just up to his waist.
>   2) (also up until) until: up to now I hadn't had a relationship.
>   3) indicating a maximum amount: the process is expected to take up to two years.
>   4) (with negative or in questions) *as good as*; *good enough for*: I was not up to her standards.
>   5) capable of or fit for: he is simply not up to the job.
>   6) the duty, responsibility, or choice of (someone): it was up to them to gauge the problem.
>   7) informal occupied or busy with: what's he been up to?

Can Anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1):

"*Towards*" means essentially "*in the direction of*".

> She came **towards** me ...

means she made a few steps in my direction ("in the direction of me").  Here "came" points that she is at the destination end of the distance.

"*Up to*" means essentially "*into the nearest vicinity of*".

> She came **up to** me...

means she completed her movement and was at the point reasonably close to "*me*", most likely the distance between "*her*" and "*me*" is such as to allow a normal conversation (or even *a very private one*, i.e. nobody else would overhear).

Both prepositions are reasonable as far as describing the motion "*she*" made.  Of course, since the task is to use that in conjunction with the other preposition, you're likely asked what *your understanding* of the differences in the meanings of the two expressions is.

> She came towards me and asked the best way to get over the situation.
>   She came up to me and asked the best way to get out of the situation.

What do you imagine when you read those sentences knowing the difference between "towards" and "up to"?  This is what you will need to explain.